# What data does steamworks.net SteamNetworkPingLocation_t require

Tags: c#, .net, ping, steamworks-api

So i've recently spend some time making a discord bot in.net that creates embeds for servers displaying some data. However sadly the A2S.inf doesn't include ping of the server so i've checked

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamNetworkingUtils

which includes EstimatePingTimeFromLocalHost which is exactly the function i'd want. However it needs teamNetworkPingLocation_t but i havn't been able to figure out what kind of data it requires. I know it requires a byte[] but i haven't been able to find any info on what data that array needs to include.

With it being a byte array there is not much i can try except trying to find the answer which i couldn't